# Commas displayed instead of selected responses from a multi-select field on Confirmation page for CiviEvent registration

Tags: civievent

When viewing the confirmation page of a CiviEvent registration form, the options selected in two different multiselect fields do not appear. Instead, for each field a series of commas equivalent to the number of options available in the field appear. This happens if I select any fewer than the full number of options available for the field.

The responses to other fields on the same form are fine, including those related to a couple of radio-button select fields.

In the attached image, Job Title and Dietary Restriction fields are examples of the issue.

Personal pronoun and several other fields displayed in the image are from fields using radio-button selections.

What could be causing this?

I've seen this Q&A but I think my concern is different and I'm on a later version of CiviCRM (5.13).
https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17129

[image: Job title and Dietary restriction fields]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now [fixed](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/14587) in 5.16.2 version. You can either upgrade CiviCRM to 5.16.2 or apply patch from [here](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/14587.patch).

Cheers

Pradeep

Comment: Pradeep, thank you very much for this answer. Next time, I will look at the current known fixes and not just the old ones!

Comment: If my answer fixed your problem than can you mark as answered so that it may help someone?